# no me borra los registros en un datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

amigos, estoy haciendo un pantalla en visual basic net, con visual studio 2017, llevo mas de 4 horas trantando de eliminar varios registros y no me lo hace, el datagrid se llena en base a una consulta que genero con sp en SQL Server, es decir no tengo datos enlazados.

Este es mi codigo:

```
Dim anFila As Integer = dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.Count()
            Dim aoLoHayo As Boolean = False

            If dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For Each aoRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvCuentaTotal.Rows
                    'Validar que ingresen las filas que no vienen vacillas
                    If aoRow IsNot Nothing Then
                        'chktraspasar
                        aoLoHayo = aoRow.Cells(3).Value
                        'If aoLoHayo = True Then
                        If Convert.ToBoolean(aoRow.Cells("Traspasar").Value) Then
                            anFila -= 1
                            dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.Remove(aoRow)
                            dgvCuentaTotal.Refresh()
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                dgvCuentaTotal.Refresh()
                'Validar que traiga registros
            End If
```

Tengo una columna con un checkbox, seis registros y el usuario marca los seis para ser borrados, y este codigo solo me elimina 3 filas, dejando las otras tres, me podrian dar una mano.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que eliminas la fila dentro del bucle y el enumerador del ciclo se pierde.

Apunta en un array u otro tipo de variable las filas a eleminar y una vez terminado de recorrer el datagridview eliminas las filas guardadas en el array o variable

Comment: Gracias Luis Carlos, segui tus recomendaciones, modifique el codigo de esta manera, agregue una variable de tipo integer, llamada anEliminar, aqui guardare el total de registros a eliminar y hice otra de tipo array llamada aoEliminar(), en esta guardo el numero de indice de la fila, al terminar el ciclo, le la variable eliminar, le resto una posicion pxq me da error de INDICE si no lo hago y al datagridview le paso la variable array para que elimine los que guarde.

Comment: Este es el codigo Luis Carlos, tal vez me das tus comentarios.
Dim aoEliminar() As Integer
Dim anEliminar As Integer
For Each aoRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvCuentaTotal.Rows
     If aoRow IsNot Nothing Then
        If Convert.ToBoolean(aoRow.Cells("Traspasar").Value) Then
           anEliminar += 1
           ReDim Preserve aoEliminar(anEliminar)
          aoEliminar(anEliminar) = aoRow.Index
       End If
   End If
 Next
For i As Integer = 0 To anEliminar - 1
dgvCuentaTotal.Rows.RemoveAt(aoEliminar(i))
dgvCuentaTotal.Refresh()
Next
dgvCuentaTotal.Refresh()End If

Comment: @alfredo.avmb me alegra haberle pódido ayudar